# TS2769 No overload matches this call

Tags: typescript, angular

Смотрю обучающий ролик на ютубе, как добавить token в ответное сообщение.
Имеется сервис, где получаем token

```
  get token (): string | null {
    const fbTokenExp = localStorage.getItem('fb-token-exp');
    if (fbTokenExp) {
      const expDate = new Date(fbTokenExp);
      if ( new Date > expDate ) {
        this.logout()
        return null
      }
      return localStorage.getItem('fb-token')
    }
    return null;
  }
```

и сам intercept где происходит добавление token в сообщение

```
intercept(req: import("@angular/common/http").HttpRequest<any>,
            next: import("@angular/common/http").HttpHandler): import("rxjs").Observable<import("@angular/common/http").HttpEvent<any>> {

    if (this.auth.isAuthenticated()) {
      req = req.clone({
        setParams: {
          auth: this.auth.token
        }
      })
    }
```

IDEA ругается на эту строку

```
auth: this.auth.token
```

Пишет, что

```
TS2769: No overload matches this call.   Overload 1 of 3, '(update: { headers?: HttpHeaders | undefined; context?: HttpContext | undefined; reportProgress?: boolean | undefined; params?: HttpParams | undefined; ... 6 more ...; setParams?: { ...; } | undefined; }): HttpRequest<...>', gave the following error.     Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.       Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.   Overload 2 of 3, '(update: { headers?: HttpHeaders | undefined; context?: HttpContext | undefined; reportProgress?: boolean | undefined; params?: HttpParams | undefined; ... 6 more ...; setParams?: { ...; } | undefined; }): HttpRequest<...>', gave the following error.     Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.       Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

Я не пойму как это исправить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SetParams имеет тип:

```
{
 [param: string]: string;
}
```

Вы же скорей всего передаете значение которое может быть undefined либо сам this.auth либо его свойство this.auth.token

Проверяйте существует ли свойство

```
if (this.auth && this.auth.token) {
  req = req.clone({
    setParams: {
      auth: this.auth.token
    }
  })
}
```

Либо используйте оператор `!` если уверены что свойство есть

```
if (this.auth.isAuthenticated()) {
    req = req.clone({
      setParams: {
        auth: this.auth!.token!
      }
    })
 }
```